# What are the consequences if I remove _USRDLL preprocessor definition?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc

I'm a beginner! I try to use shared MFC libraries with an old dll, but when I compile it with VC6 I obtain the error "LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined".
I found so many explanations, but only removing "_USRDLL" the issue disappear and the dll work. Now I'm a bit confused about the consequences of this action.

In addition, I read on MSDN that a USRDLL correspond to a regular DLL that statically links to MFC. So, when I create a new Win32 Dynamic-Link Library with VC6, why "_USRDLL" is already present if I choose in Project->Setting->Genaral "Use MFC in a shared dll" or "Not using MFC"?
Sorry for my bad english and thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4):

A regular DLL with the MFC never has a DllMain.
This is covered by the CWinApp object.

Only Extension DLLs have a DllMAin. Read [TN033](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn033-dll-version-of-mfc).
_USRDLL has to be defined in this case!

Comment: Thank you, but I've already read TN033 and TN011. Inside my DLL there isn't a DllMain, maybe is something else that produce the error. Perhaps one of the other library that I call, but I didn't find what one.
The other question is why everything work fine if I remove _USRDLL preprocessor definition, and what will change in the DLL if I do that.
Thank you very much for any help! ;-)

Comment: Just look into the MFC headers. If _USRDLL is not defined, a lot of code isn't compiled or deklarations change. Just look into the Header. Also the linker is instrcuted to include different modules.